# What is VM.swappiness a percentage of?

Tags: linux, swap

IF `VM.swappiness=50` and I have a 60G RAM, with 20 used by an application and 20G by cache buffer, then technically I am using 40 / 60 = 66% of my RAM. Since this is greater than swappiness threshold, will this cause swapping in my instance?

I expect `VM.swappiness` to only rely on USED memory that excludes buffer/cache. Is that not the case?

Comment: when all else fails, read the documentation https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.22/source/Documentation/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.rst#L843

Comment: what is filesystem paging?

Comment: filesystem paging is when a filesystem reads or writes a page of memory from or to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, read the docs.  But I'll summarize..
(Not from the docs) It's VERY commonly stated online, like I've seen it all over the case, that vm.swappiness is a percentage of free memory, the default 60 would mean to start swapping when 60% of memory is free.  This is not the case.

vm.swappiness (this is paraphrased from the docs, and I've looked at the source code and the docs are accurate).. So the kernel memory management system wants to free up some RAM... it'll either kick stuff out of the page cache (this is the disk cache), or write some stuff out to swap.  vm.swappiness determines "relative I/O cost" of swapping something out versus dropping some disk cache (i.e. how much you think it'll slow the system down.)   Total value is 200, so default vm.swappiness=60 means page cache is 140 (200-60).  140/60=2.33, so it considers regular disk I/o to be about 2.33 times the speed of swap.  Settings vm.swappiness=100 means swap and disk I/O are equally fast; on modern kernels, in case you had a fast swap system (like some auxillary RAM disk or optane ssds or something) you can even set vm.swappiness over 100 to say 150 to say swap is faster than your regular disk.

(not in the docs) A comment on the default, vm.swappiness=60.  That was the default when I first started using Linux, on a 16mhz 386 with 4MB RAM and a 40MB hard disk, on these older systems the execution speed was low enough you could get into heavy swap and still get like 10-20% of your normal speed; and you dealt with relatively small files compared to now (so less "stuff" flowing through the disk cache).  You now have systems with GBs of RAM, 100s of GBs to TBs of disk space, much larger files with much higher disk I/O rates. It's common for both server and desktop setups now to recommend values of 1 or 10; and I think this is now appropriate, heavy disk I/O tends to make the system swap excessively on a modern system with the default 60, maintaining many GBs of disk cache by swapping out GBs of code which really slows things down over all compared to a lower swappiness value.